# Laravel PHP: Uploading Image with Large file size results in 'getClientOriginalName()' being 'null'

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm using Laravel PHP and I have a photo gallery that allows the user to upload images to an album.  When I upload images that are a normal file size , less than 8MB, they are uploaded and saved to the photo album just fine.  However, when I try to upload images that are bigger than 8MB, I keep getting a '**Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null' error**.

To account for large images being uploaded to the photo gallery, I edited 'nginx.conf' and 'php.ini' respectively so that the previous line in '**nginx.conf**'

```
client_max_body_size 8M;
```

was changed to

```
client_max_body_size 25M;
```

And in 'php.ini', this line:

```
upload_max_filesize = 8M
```

Was changed to:

```
upload_max_filesize = 25M
```

After making the changes in both these files, in Putty I ran:

```
sudo service nginx restart
sudo service php5-fpm restart
```

Here is my controller for uploading new photos:

```
public function store()
{
    $input = \Input::all();

    $validation = new Validators\Stone_Photo;

        $filename = str_random(4) . \Input::file('photo_path')->getClientOriginalName();
        $destination = "uploads/photos/";
        $upload = \Input::file('photo_path')->move($destination, $filename);

        if( $upload == false )
        {
            return \Redirect::to('home.index')
            ->withInput()
            ->withErrors($validation->errors)
            ->with('message', 'Could not upload picture');
        }

        $this->stone_photo->create($input, $filename);
        return \Redirect::route('show_stone', array('id' => $input['stone_id']));
}
```

So once again, photos that are under 8MB are still uploaded fine but when I try to upload a photo that is 9MB or over, I keep getting the error '**Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null' error** and I don't know why.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your controller action is `store` I'm guessing you have a restfull controller and for that action the HTTP method is `POST`. If that's the case you need to make sure you set also set the `post_max_size` in your `php.ini`:

```
post_max_size = 25M
```

Otherwise `upload_max_filesize` will be overriden for any `POST` request by the value of `post_max_size` (which is by default 8MB).

Comment: This sounds like a good solution.  When I return to my work computer, I will definitely try this out first thing in the morning.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly!  I edited my 'php.ini' file as you said and now I can post images with high memory sizes.  Thank you so much Bogdan!